# Recursion does not seem to work in my minimax implementation

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, minimax

The `miniMax` function returns an object consisting of an index and score as intended, but it does not visit as many states as expected.

Here is the code:

```js
const human = 'X'
const ai = 'O'
const winOptions = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
const emptyCells = (layout) => {
  return layout.map((item, index) => {
    return (item === '' ? index : null)
  }).filter((item) => item !== null)
}
const checkWin = (layout) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < winOptions.length; i += 1) {
    const [a, b, c] = winOptions[i]
    if (layout[a] === 'X' && layout[a] === layout[b] && layout[b] === layout[c]) {
      return -1
    }
    if (layout[a] === 'O' && layout[a] === layout[b] && layout[b] === layout[c]) {
      return 1
    }
  }
  return false
}

function miniMax (gameLayout, player) {
  const empty = emptyCells(gameLayout)
  if (checkWin(gameLayout) === 1) {
    return { score: 10 }
  } else if (checkWin(gameLayout) === -1) {
    return { score: -10 }
  } else if (empty.length === 0) {
    return { score: 0 }
  }
  const moves = []
  for (let i = 0; i < empty.length; i++) {
    const move = {}
    move.index = empty[i]
    player === 'O' ? gameLayout[empty[i]] = 'O' : gameLayout[empty[i]] = 'X'
    player === 'O' ? move.score = miniMax(gameLayout, human).score : move.score = miniMax(gameLayout, ai).score
    moves.push(move)
  }
  let bestMove
  if (player === 'O') {
    bestMove = moves.reduce((acc, curr, i) => moves[acc].score > curr.score ? acc : i, 0)
  } else {
    bestMove = moves.reduce((acc, curr, i) => moves[acc].score < curr.score ? acc : i, 0)
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(moves))
  return moves[bestMove]
}

// Example run:
const layout = ["X", "", "" , 
                "" , "", "" ,
                "" , "", "O"]
miniMax(layout, "X")
```

Here is how it looks, with the console output as produced in the above snippet:

[image: screenshot how its going]

Clearly my minimax implementation for Tic Tac Toe doesn't work as expected. The console should be flooded with output, since there are many options for enumeration. But it displays only 6 lines of output, as if the recursion does not work and does not go into every possible option.

I've been trying to find a bug for days... What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We would like to help answer your question, but you need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. This will allow people to experiment with the code to analyze the issue. It is extremely difficult to read tens of lines of unfamiliar code and pinpoint what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the played moves are not taken back. The function is called recursively as intended, but then the board is full and it never changes after that. By consequence `empty.length` will be 0 for all execution contexts, and the recursion will unwind without making other moves.

To fix this, add this line after the `push`:

```
gameLayout[empty[i]] = ''; // take back
```

Comment: thank you very much ! Its realy work now. my code always does not work because of one line...
Thank you again !